# Batch script to RENAME file with current date

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to simply rename a file replacing the date in the file name with the current date.  I am getting "syntax is incorrect error"

Here is my code:

```
echo on
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%


set "_year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "_month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "_day=%MyDate:~6,2%"

REN C:\Users\xyz125\Documents\Erics's Docs\scripts\"test file (20150112).txt" "test file (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"

pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong quoting: instead of

```
REN C:\Users\xyz125\Documents\Erics's Docs\scripts\"test file (20150112).txt" "test file (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"
rem                                                ^
```

should be

```
REN "C:\Users\xyz125\Documents\Erics's Docs\scripts\test file (20150112).txt" "test file (%_year%%_month%%_day%).txt"
rem ^
```